# How to pass variable keyword-arguments when calling a function

Tags: python, arguments, keyword, keyword-argument

I am trying to write a function which tests out different hyper-parameters with a list of values. I want to use this function to automatically run through the specified hyper-parameter and apply the values that are specified. What would be the correct way to do that? 
The correct way to call the logistic regression function would be:

```
lg = LogisticRegression(solver = "liblinear", max_iter = 10000, C=10)

def hyperparameter_tuning(parameter, test_values):
  for value in test_values:
     lg = LogisticRegression(solver = "liblinear", max_iter = 10000, parameter=value)
```

When calling the function like this:

```
hyperparameter_tuning("C",[0.1, 1, 10, 100])
```

I get the error message:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'parameter'
```

Comment: `LogisticRegression(solver = "liblinear", max_iter = 10000, parameter=value)` does `LogisticRegression` have a `parameter` argument?

Comment: No, the correct argument is C=xyz. But this is exactly what I'm trying to achieve here. I want to pass the argument name when calling the hyperparameter_tuning() function

Comment: I think your are confused.... `parameter=value` is passing a `value` to `LogisticRegression ` by a key word. Your passed in `parameter` is never being used. I don't know how to use your function but you should look at how keyword arguments work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `**` for that:

```
lg = LogisticRegression(solver = "liblinear", max_iter = 10000, **{parameter: value})
```

Comment: Lapsus! hahahaha